# UISegmentedControl inside UITableViewCell automatically returns to the first segment

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, uisegmentedcontrol

I have a table view with a header section and inside there is a segmented control. When I select the second segment, after milliseconds, it returns automatically to the first segment. Why?

My code:

```
-(UIView *) tableView:(UITableView *)tableView viewForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section {
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Header";
    UITableViewCell *headerView = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    if (headerView == nil){
        [NSException raise:@"headerView == nil.." format:@"No cells with matching CellIdentifier loaded from your storyboard"];
    }
    UISegmentedControl *segmentedControl = (UISegmentedControl *)[headerView viewWithTag:123];
    [segmentedControl addTarget:self action:@selector(typeChanged:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventValueChanged];

    return headerView;
}


-(void)typeChanged:(id)sender{
    UISegmentedControl *segment=(UISegmentedControl*)sender;
    NSLog(@"index %li",(long)segment.selectedSegmentIndex);
}
```

Thanks

Comment: Why are you dequeuing a table view cell for the header view? That makes no sense at all.

Comment: Can you make an example? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I suggest not code in this way, some kind like hack code.
See your code, when the tableView refresh the section header, it call the function, and headerView won't be nil, because tableView create a new one for you, obviously its selection is the first segment.

Comment: Can you make an example? I prefer to use the storyboard as now to create the segmented control. Thanks

Comment: You can print the header view to see its memory address,  Is the segment  the same one before your click and after your click？I don't think they are the same

Comment: The problem is that method prints only the index, doesn't reload the table